# How to draw Temperley-Lieb diagrams in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

Could someone please provide some sort of template for drawing some basic [Temperley-Lieb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperley%E2%80%93Lieb_algebra) diagrams in LateX?

I have tried using the tikz package, but am still unable to make any progress.

Here is one example of what such diagrams look like:

[image]

Comment: My suspicion is that not everyone who uses \*TeX knows what Temperley-Lieb diagrams are. Perhaps you could be *both* a little more helpful in what you are looking for *and* add some code that helps us understand what 'I have tried using the tikz package' means.

Comment: @jon Maybe the OP is waiting for Temperley-Lieb to show up? Presumably s/he/it knows?

Comment: @cfr -- ha, indeed. Something/one must..!

Answer (score 5):

Here is some starting example :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
% define some useful styles to draw the strings
\tikzset{
  pt/.style={insert path={node[scale=2]{.}}},
  dnup/.style={insert path={ [pt] .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,-1) .. +(#1,2) [pt]}},
  dndn/.style={insert path={ [pt] .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,1) .. +(#1,0) [pt]}},
  upup/.style={insert path={ [pt] .. controls +(0,-1) and +(0,-1) .. +(#1,0) [pt]}},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (7,2);
    \draw (1,0) [dnup=2];
    \draw (1,2) [upup=1];
    \draw (2,0) [dnup=2];
    \draw (3,0) [dndn=1];
    \draw (5,0) [dnup=0];
    \draw (6,0) [dnup=0];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]