# How can one draw the "input-output" forms in a braid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots, braids

How would one draw diagrams like these? I wasn't able to find any documentation regarding the closed loops, or cups and caps in the `braids` package.

[image][image]

Reference: *Knots and Physics*, 4th ed. by Louis Kauffman.

Comment: The main point of `braids` is to find the intersections of strands and draw these prettily. The braids always get drawn top to bottom with no loop. Your sketches just look like a bunch of lines/curves and a few bits and bobs. I probably would use `tikz-cd` because it gives a nice interface for a TikZ matrix and to draw lines between its entries.

Comment: That is not a braid, but a knot(without crossings, so the `knots` package it also not helpful).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I want to represent a variation of braids actually. Kauffman defines new objects (_U_i_), which join adjacent strands of a braid. But yes, as you say, these new elements do not belong to the braid group per se.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360940/how-to-draw-temperley-lieb-diagrams-in-latex

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, xscale=0.5]
\foreach \myy in {3,6,...,12}{
\draw[dashed] (-1,\myy) -- (6,\myy);
}
\draw
(0,6)
arc[radius=1, start angle=180, delta angle=-180]
arc[radius=1, start angle=180, delta angle=180]
-- (4,12)
to[out=90, in=90+50, looseness=1.2] (6,12)
to[out=-90+50, in=90-50, looseness=0.8] (6,3)
to[out=-90-50, in=-90, looseness=1.2] (4,3)
arc[radius=1, start angle=0, delta angle=180]
to[out=-90, in=-90-50, looseness=0.8] (6,2.5)
to[out=90-50, in=-90+50, looseness=1] (6,12.5)
to[out=90+50, in=90, looseness=0.8] (2,12)
arc[radius=1, start angle=0, delta angle=-180]
to[out=90, in=90+50, looseness=0.8] (6,13)
to[out=-90+50, in=90-50, looseness=1.2] (6,2)
to[out=-90-50, in=-90, looseness=0.8] (0,3)
-- cycle;
\draw (1,9) circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A long closed curve]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping that there was some easier way to do achieve this using the `braids` package.